# Working with arrays of Windows form elements

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, foreach, element

What I have:

```
label4.Show();
label5.Show();
pictureBox3.Show();
textBox1.Show();
button3.Show();
```

What I need (example, but doesn't work):

```
Object[] arr = new Object[] { label4,label5,pictureBox3,textBox1,button3 };
foreach (Object o in arr)
{
    o.Show();
}
```

Is it to possible to do something like this code?

Comment: Use `Control[]` instead of `Object[]`.

Comment: well it depends on what label4 label5 etc are really ?

Comment: erik, is there a show method on control ?

Comment: `Control[]` works, thank you!

Comment: Yes, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: yes eric, good learning for me :) never used show on controls

Comment: Cant you use the Visible property?

Answer (score 6):

Use `Control[]` instead of `Object[]`. `Control` has the `Show` method, [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When I need to do something like this, I usually find it more convenient to group controls into a `Panel`, then you can just show and hide the panel without having to muck with the individual controls. That only works if the controls are arranged close together on your form, but if they are you might consider this approach.